# Train an object detection classifier using tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection

help me out from the error which I couldn't overcome

after using the below command

```
python generate_tfrecord.py --csv_input=images/train_labels.csv --image_dir=images/train --output_path=train.record
```

I received the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\asus\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\asus\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\asus\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\asus\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\asus\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "generate_tfrecord.py", line 18, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "C:\Users\asus\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 101, in <module>
    from tensorflow_core import *
  File "C:\Users\asus\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "C:\Users\asus\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "C:\Users\asus\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "C:\Users\asus\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\Users\asus\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\asus\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\asus\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\asus\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\asus\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\asus\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\asus\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors
for some common reasons and solutions.  
Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that you either don't have TensorFlow installed correctly or some of its libraries didn't. You should try installing it with `conda install tensorflow==2.0`

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by downloading and installing visual studio 2017-2019 x86 and x64 from here:

Other solution is downgrading tensorflow to 2.0:

```
pip install tensorflow==2.0
```

I have Python 3.7.6, CUDA 10.1 and cuDNN for CUDA 10.1 and I have followed this requeriments:

If this not work for you then create virtual env.

```
conda create -n tf-gpu tensorflow-gpu
conda activate tf-gpu
```